# AT Commands doesn't work :: WinSock Bluetooth Connection

Tags: android, c++, bluetooth, winsock, at-command

I'm creating windows application in C++, which connect's PC with mobile via bluetooth and winsock. Allow's you to call and send messages from mobile via computer.

I'm using AT command's to tell mobile what i want to do. Pair with mobile device and force a call with At command

```
ATD+420******;
```

works perfect, but all commands for handling SMS like

```
AT+CMGL, AT+CMGF, AT+CMGS etc.
```

phone probably doesnt recognize them and returns ERROR.

Here is code which connects PC with mobile via bluetooth and socket:

```
SOCKADDR_BTH RemoteEndPoint;
RemoteEndPoint.port = 0;
RemoteEndPoint.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
RemoteEndPoint.btAddr = m_foundDevices[m_deviceIndex].Address.ullLong;
RemoteEndPoint.serviceClassId = HandsfreeServiceClass_UUID;
int BTHAddrLength = sizeof(RemoteEndPoint);

// Create the socket.
if ((m_localSocket = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    // handle error.
}

// Connect the socket.
if ((iResult = connect(m_localSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&RemoteEndPoint,     sizeof(RemoteEndPoint))) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    // handle error.
}
```

Notice line

```
RemoteEndPoint.serviceClassId = HandsfreeServiceClass_UUID
```

I think the problem is here, becouse u cant send sms from Handsfree, but when i use another UUID, it doesnt even pair with mobile.

=== Here is just for info, how am i sending and receiving data from mobile ===

```
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN] = "";
const char *sendbuf = "AT+CMGL\r";
int len = (int)strlen(sendbuf);
if ((iResult = send(m_localSocket, sendbuf, len, MSG_OOB)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    // handle error. return ~0
}

if ((iResult = recv(m_localSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    // handle error. return ~0
}    
// Here recvbuf == "\r\nERROR\r\n"
```

-- I would like to find out the problem, why AT command's for SMS doesnt work.

Thank you for any advices!
If you have any question's about problem, i'll kindly explain.
Regards,
Filip.

**EDIT**
I found out answer "If you want to send SMS Messages, a Server Socket will be needed on the GSM Device", but after hours of googling i have no clue how to do that. Any suggestion's? Thank you.